# Regex to remove decimal values

Tags: regex

Given a timestamp in ISO 8601 format below:

```
2012-04-21T01:56:00.581550
```

what regular expression would remove the decimal point and the millisecond precision? In other words, a regex that applies to the above and returns the following:

```
2012-04-21T01:56:00
```

This is probably very simple, but not being particular familiar with regex I am unsure how to approach the solution. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use regex, you can use `"[.][0-9]+$"` and replace it with an empty string `""`.
It is easier to locate the trailing `'.'`, and chop off the string at its index. In C#, that would be

```
myStr = myStr.Substring(0, myStr.LastIndexOf('.')-1);
```

Comment: I agree that regex is overkill here and even likely prone to errors.

Comment: Thanks, there is a method to split a string based upon a delimiter in the language I am using so that seems to be the better way.

Answer (score 2):

This regex `^[\w\-:]+` will only match up to the period and excluding it. You can use this to *find* the part of the time-stamp you want.

- `^` is the beginning of the string.
- `\w` is any "word".
- `\-` includes the hyphen.
- `:` includes the colon.
- These placed in `[]` means only matching these characters.
- The `+` means matching one or many instances of those characters.

Since the period (`.`) is not included, the regex will stop matching when it gets to that.

Answer (score 2):

why do you want to use regex?
use string operations

in python :

```
>>> "2012-04-21T01:56:00.581550".split(".")
['2012-04-21T01:56:00', '581550']
>>> "2012-04-21T01:56:00.581550".split(".")[0]
'2012-04-21T01:56:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s/\..*$//
```

It looks like you can assume there will only be one dot. The above sed expression finds a dot, then replaces everything after that dot up until the newline with nothing.

Without sed: replace `\..*$` with the empty string `""`

`\.` is the literal period (have to escape it because `.` means any character)

`.*` means any and all characters

`$` means end of line

Answer (score 0):

***Code:***

```
$_ = '2012-04-21T01:56:00.581550';
s/\.\d*//;
print $_, "\n";
```

***Test:***

http://ideone.com/52hij

***Output:***

```
2012-04-21T01:56:00
```